# Django 1.7 makemigrations not having an effect

Tags: django, database-migration, heroku-postgres, django-1.7, django-migrations

I keep running `python manage.py makemigrations` on my heroku server, but no matter how many times I run it I get:

```
$heroku run python manage.py makemigrations
Running `python manage.py makemigrations` attached to terminal... up, run.2680
Migrations for 'default':
  0002_auto_20141120_2007.py:
    - Alter field user on usersocialauth
```

and if I run `heroku run python manage.py migrate`

it comes back with:

```
Running `python manage.py migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.1285
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: baflist_core, rest_framework, localflavor, storages
  Apply all migrations: admin, userAccount, contenttypes, sessions, default, location, messaging, forum, auth, posts
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
  Installing custom SQL...
  Installing indexes...
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

Admittedly, I only know enough about postgres and migrations to be dangerous, so I figured I'd ask on here. Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: You should not be running makemigrations on the server. Run it locally, add the created migration files to git, and push it, and heroku will automatically run migrate for you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After local migration completed you should have migration file(s) on `<your django app>/migrations` folder Ex (restapi is mine django application here):

```
/Django/app/folder/restapi/migrations$ ls
0001_initial.py  0001_initial.pyc  __init__.py  __init__.pyc
```

So you should commit migrations file manually:

```
heroku$ git commit restapi/migrations/0001_initial.py -m "migrations file"
heroku$ git push heroku master
```

Note: NO heroku will not run migrate on you app automatically! I have checked this!
You should run migrate for your app after you push the file:

heroku$ heroku run python manage.py migrate restapi
Running `python manage.py migrate restapi` attached to terminal... up, run.4602
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: restapi
Running migrations:
  Applying restapi.0001_initial... OK

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I was scratching my head on this issue as my settings file reflected the heroku settings and I had not yet created another dev settings file to run things locally then pushing back to heroku. +1!